# How can I detect collision between two objects

Tags: c#, unity, collision-detection

I have some code that when I click on an object with my mouse it will change it to another object. I'm using this code to change an object into a shattered version I made of it for destruction purposes. How could I change the mouse down function into a function that would activate when the object is touched by another object ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Destruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject destructionPiece;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Instantiate (destructionPiece, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you basically asking how can you detect collision between 2 objects ? You can find thousands of results if you just google it. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/on-collision-enter) is an official tutorial from unity.

Comment: Check out the collision section on the unity docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html This depends on if you are using 3D or 2D(just add a "2D" onto the end) and you will also need to look up rigidbodys and add colliders to your objects.